# How do I get the "Application" project template to re-appear in Qt Creator IDE?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I just installed Qt Creator IDE and when I first started the QtCreator.exe file, and clicked New Project, it showed the "Application" template from where I could choose the Qt Gui Application type. But now when I run it again it only shows some templates (the image link is provided)

How do I bring back the "Application" template again?

[image]

Comment: the same thing is happening to me, only the 'Libraries' templates in the wizard, no 'Applications' templates.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Build & Run > Qt Versions tab and see if your installed Qt versions are recognized.

Re-installing the Qt library, Qt Creator, or the whole QtSDK if it's your case is always a good idea.

**EDIT:** So for some reason Qt Creator has stopped detecting your Qt library. You don't need the SDK separately. Press the "Add" button in that dialog and locate your installed `qmake.exe` file (it should be in the `bin` directory of where you installed the Qt library).
If still not recognized, do a clean reinstall of the library.

Comment: There is not a single thing in the Qt Versions. :/ Here is what I did from the top:

1. I downloaded Qt IDE and installed it.
2. Then Installed the Qt Library.

Do I need to install the SDK too? Won't it just make 2 Qt Creator.exe files?

Comment: @boxofapps Doing two separate installs raises the possibility that QtCreator isn't seeing the relevant dlls.  I would wipe your current installations clean install the entire QtSDK, one single install.

Comment: thanks @Hossein, after adding the path to qmake.exe, the 'Applications' templates appear again! great! :)